# responsive card on mobile devices

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I have 3 cards that I use translate to move them 50% of the size to the top of the div

but I can't make it responsive on mobile devices and my text also comes out of the card on mobile devices:

[image]

For some reason the screen width is passing

code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ background: "red", height: "300px" }} />
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          transform: "translateY(-50%)"
        }}
      >
        <Cards />
        <Cards />
        <Cards />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

card:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import bgLogo from "./card-top-wave.png";
import React from "react";
const FlexColumn = css`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  height: 430px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
`;

const Card = styled.div`
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 430px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-clip: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  :before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    background-image: url(${bgLogo});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: contain;
  }
`;
const WrapperImg = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(${({ background }) => background});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
`;
const WrapperTexts = styled.div`
  ${FlexColumn}
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(${({ background }) => background});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  & > h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #243f93;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0;
  }
  & > p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #333;
  }
`;

export const Cards = props => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Card>
        <WrapperImg background={props.background} />
        <WrapperTexts>
          <h4>aaaaaaaaa</h4>
          <p>bbbbbbbbb</p>
        </WrapperTexts>
      </Card>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-heisenberg-3guyu

on desktop it's all ok:

[image]

Comment: You using absolute values likes `height: 430px` and `width: 380px`, you need to use relative values.

Comment: ok and how would i solve this? using%
vh
vw
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be my own opinion, but when multiple containers set a height to constrain one thing, it becomes tricky to debug.

In your case, you likely needed `height: 100%` somewhere.
This is what I tried: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-bose-mnfv1

Mainly took away a few height settings and set the Text's wrapper to 100% height.

```
const WrapperTexts = styled.div`
  ${FlexColumn}
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(${({ background }) => background});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  & > h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #243f93;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0;
  }
  & > p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #333;
  }
`;
```

Edit, for the cards to wrap, you need to set `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Cards } from "./Card";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ background: "red", height: "300px" }} />
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          transform: "translateY(-50%)"
        }}
      >
        <Cards />
        <Cards />
        <Cards />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: but what about the card is over my total screen width.

Comment: What is the expected behavior when the screen is too small for the three boxes? Do you expect the cards to wrap to the next line? Do you expect them to shrink? Your red container and the three cards are siblings, they likely do not know each other's width.

Comment: yI would need one to be under the other like columns

could you explain to me "are brothers and do not know the width of each other?"

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean. Could you please give me an image/mock up of what you want it to look like?

Comment: I updated the codepen & the above code, please see if that's what you want.